# install a ServletContextListener in axis2, Tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat, apache-axis, servletcontextlistener

I tried to integrate a servletcontextlistener in my axis2 app in Apache Tomcat 7.
I followed all instructions, but when I start tomcat, I get the following error:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.pmm.cpsserver.coolarts.daemon.CoolArtsListener
... error.

This is my class:

```
public class CoolArtsListener implements ServletContextListener {
  //protected Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());
  private ServletContext m_oApplication = null;

  @Override
  public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent oEvent)
  {
    this.m_oApplication = oEvent.getServletContext();
    System.out.println("the CA - Listener is called");        
  }

  @Override
  public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0)
  {
    System.out.println("The CA - Listener is destroyed");
  } 
}
```

and published the class in the web.xml of the axis2 app.

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>ch.pmm.cpsserver.coolarts.daemon.CoolArtsListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Is a missing lib the reason for this behaviour? 
If so, what libs are required for this functionality? Or is there another reason?

Comment: Is the CoolArtsListener in a jar, or is a class in your project?

Comment: it's a class in my project at the location "ch.pmm.cpsserver.coolarts.daemon"